# How to display custom text in a new line?

Tags: html, css

I want to show the text "You save ..." in a new line. I do not how to do. Please guide me. Please click for more details [jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/hassaan39/23Lo1yzv/)

```html
<div class="product-wrap first">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="product-image"><a href="#">Img area</a>

    </div>
    <div class="product-content">
      <div class="product-name"> <a class="fontcolor" href="#">Motorcycle Leather Boots (4Riders Boots Always)</a>

      </div>
      <div class="price-box">
        <p class="special-price"><span class="price" id="product-price-77">£53.68</span>
        </p>
        <p class="old-price"><span class="price" id="old-price-77">£84.15</span>
        </p> <span class="div-discount"><b>You save </b> <em><i>36.21</i><u>%</u></em></span>

      </div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
span.div-discount {
    /* display: block; */
    clear: left;
    display: block;
}
```

just add this to your css it will work

here is the demo please look out

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/23Lo1yzv/4/)

Answer (score 2):

Make use of `<br/>` tag here! It breaks the line

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/23Lo1yzv/1/)**

---

**UPDATE**

Add below properties to your `.product-wrap .item .price-box` class `css`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/23Lo1yzv/3/)**

```
.product-wrap .item .price-box {
    margin-top: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:auto; //Set this
    float:left; //and keep it float left
}
```

Comment: I want to use only css. I cant add break tags here. Its a theme. And its HTML is building from some magento plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Add Css

```
.div-discount b, .div-discount em{display:block;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your paragraphs are set to float, which is fine, but you will need to clear and wrap it in a div and set that div to block so it extends the fill width.

Then you want to set the div-discount class to block too.

CSS:

```
.amounts {
    display: block;
}
.div-discount {
    color: #b50016;
    display: block;
}
.clr-both {
    clear: both;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="amounts">
    <p class="special-price"><span class="price" id="product-price-77">£53.68</span>
    </p>
    <p class="old-price"><span class="price" id="old-price-77">£84.15</span>
    </p> 
    <div class="clr-both"></div>
</div>
<span class="div-discount"><b>You save </b> <em><i>36.21</i><u>%</u>
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4t9f6yd/4/)

Answer (score 0):

The b element in HTML stands for bold. Add the rule in CSS defines is display as inline. It means the elements which possess inline or inline-block properties will be shown on same line. So If we want to show our custom text on a new line, we have to change its style from display inline to display as block.

```
.div-discount b{ display:block;}
```